# HTML CSS div tag property confusion

Tags: html, css

Been researching how to solve an issue with a header banner I'm doing by seeing how other sites do it, I came across a tag's property that confuses me.
I understand that one can "style" an HTML tag inline via `<div class="className" style="width=100%">`...I came across this tag that I don't understand what it actually does `<div class="className" width="1">`.
Does the *width="1"* mean it spans 100% the width of the browser's viewing area?

Comment: width is an obsolete attribute [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/width)

Comment: Thanks @Sfili_81.  
IK that most inline tag styling is not the best practice and it's best to leave the styling to CSS and also some have been made obsolete.  
It was just that I was curious of what it did....BTW thanks for the link with the explanation.

Comment: Pay no attention to that link. That's for XUL, not HTML. A width attribute on a DIV element does nothing.

Comment: OMG sorry, i've posted the wrong link. @Alohci your comment is correct and the link i want to share is this [w3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/obsolete.html)

Comment: No worries...it still somehow answered the question of the width="1" meant... :) ....."preferred width of the box is 1 pixels"